# Compile cython module works in 32bits but not in 64 bits [Windows]

Tags: python, windows, numpy, 64-bit, cython

I have a cython module (using numpy) which compiles and works in 32 bits doing the following thing:

```
C:\Python27_x86\Scripts\cython.exe OrderC.pyx
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27_x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27_x86\include -IC:\Python27_x86\PC -c OrderC.c -o OrderC.o
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s OrderC.o -LC:\Python27_x86\libs -LC:\Python27_x86\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o OrderC.pyd
```

But it is not working when I am trying to compile with the equivalent in 64 bits:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\cython.exe OrderC.pyx
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c OrderC.c -o OrderC.o
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s OrderC.o -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o OrderC.pyd
```

Actually, it is the third line which fails and gives a lof of errors:

```
OrderC.o:OrderC.c:(.text+0x43f2c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
...
OrderC.o:OrderC.c:(.text+0x603a9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_Ready'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: OrderC.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
```

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Is it because mingw is only compiling 32 bits ? Could you help me a bit please ?

Thanks

Comment: Cython has separate packages for 32bit and 64 bit machines - please go through - https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki

Comment: Thanks to this link : http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/30503023/, the compilation works but I have the following error at execution: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. Any help ? Thanks